# Azure Virtual Network Gateway - when creating says my existing vnets cannot be associated to virtual network gateway

Tags: networking, virtualization, azure, gateway

I'm creating a virtual network connection using existing virtual networks, vnet1 and vnet2 and they are already active with VMs on them, and are also in the same region.  When i go to select the virtual network the drop down shows them and says they are not available to be assigned to the new virtual network connection, says cannot be associated to virtual network gateway and I cannot figure out why.

I've done this many times before and can't figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Any chance they are classic vnets?